# Excel color scale with outlier

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm working with valuta in Excel and need to visually represent the biggest expenses for my job. Here is an example of how I do it now:

[image]

It's a simple 3 color scale from green to red via yellow with green as minimum, yellow at 50 percentile and red at maximum.

You see that there isn't a lot of difference in color for the numbers between 0 and 25 euro.

Is it possible to detect the outlier(s) (can be multiple) and "ignore" that one for the lower values? I'd like something similar like I have but with more visible color variation on the lower end of the spectrum.

Answer (score 4):

You can set "minimum value" for conditional formatting, this case Excel will consider everything below that to be coloured as minimum and won't calculate with the whole range:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but that's also what I've tried but the values are different for each set which would have me set a minimum value for each set myself which is too much work. Thank you for the suggestion but I think I'll keep it like it is :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Máté Juhász's answer, in the "Editing formatting rule" window, beside setting "numbers", you can also choose "percentile", so there is no need to manually set a minimum or maximum value. For example, you can use red-3%, yellow-50%, green-97% to prevent the extreme value from affecting the colors extremely.